# pandas column[value] + previous columns[value2] like equity curve in excel?

Tags: python, pandas

**strong text**how to calculate that curve in pandas ?
[excel curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsbLG.jpg)
**start curve at 10**

```
 A  curve  i_want_that
0  1    NaN           10
1  5    6.0           15
2  3    8.0           18
3  4    7.0           22
4  5    9.0           27
5  6   11.0           33
6  7   13.0           40
7  8   15.0           48
```

Comment: Please don't post a link to an image of anonymous data, it's useless to the community. Post raw text data, your code, any errors, and desired output

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 5, 3, 4,5,6,7,8]})
df['curve'] = df['A'] + df['A'].shift(1)
df['i_want_that']=[10,15,18,22,27,33,40,48]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 5, 3, 4]})
df['curve'] = df['A'] - df['A'].shift(1)
```

As you wanted:

```
df['whatYouWant'] = 9 + df['A'].cumsum()
```

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 5, 3, 4,5,6,7,8]})
df['curve'] = df['A'] + df['A'].shift(1)
df['i_want_that']=[10,15,18,22,27,33,40,48]